# is working with IContainers a better idea that ObjectFactory directly (structuremap)?

Tags: c#, structuremap

specifically, will working with containers as opposed to the static ObjectFactory let me keep multiple concurrent configurations, or are containers singletons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Containers are only Singletons if they are static. There are lots of issues with static types, particularly with regards to Testability, so I definitely prefer working with container instances myself.

Comment: so two containers will keep two separate model definitions?

Comment: @kolosy: Yes, if you configure them differently :)